# Securely eval user defined calculation

Tags: javascript, security

I need to allow user defined calculations, which are stored as strings. The formula are parsed dynamically before being executed by replacing variables with actual values.

In this context only people belonging to the same client account could potentially inject malicious code on each other, e.g. a rogue employee attacking colleagues, which is bad enough.

Examples I can think of (I'm sure there is more):

```
"{x} * {y} * function() {...}()"
"{x} * {y} * eval(...)"

// replace variables

eval( "above input strings" )
```

Now I'm looking for ideas on how to secure this. What is needed to reduce the risk for running eval() in the first place or are there alternatives that don't require to write a complicated parser?

Comment: In this case it's an offline web app that runs in a browser as well as wrapped in Apache Cordova. Trying http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/ now.

Comment: Alternatively I have the option of server-side string filtering.

Comment: Can't the calculations simply be handled server-side?

Comment: No, it's an offline app where a user within the scope of his organizational account can define calculations that are executed offline again. The server (actually an API) is only a repository for these definitions.

Comment: Black list filtering is never secure - you can get close, but someone will eventually discover way round it. How does your offline JavaScript run? In the context of a browser or an application where you have control of the global objects?

Comment: It runs in the context of a desktop browser, UIWebView on iOS, Win8 javascript app or Android Webview. All of these are sandboxed except Windows 8, which gives access to the whole filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem where I needed to run untrusted javascript that was written by a third party.  If you just want it to be simple, you can use a WebWorker, which spawns a separate thread which does not have access to global variables like `window`.

Note: WebWorker requires HTML5.

Create a "worker.js" file:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    postMessage(eval(e.data));
};
```

Then in your main javascript file:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert('The answer is ' + e.data);
    worker.terminate(); // to free up the resources
};
var my_already_parsed_function = '3+5+6';
worker.postMessage(my_already_parsed_function);
```

Comment: [OWASP don't recommend this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Web_Workers): `While Web Workers don't have access to DOM of the calling page, malicious Web Workers can use excessive CPU for computation, leading to Denial of Service condition or abuse Cross Origin Resource Sharing for further exploitation. Ensure code in all Web Workers scripts is not malevolent. Don't allow creating Web Worker scripts from user supplied input.`

Comment: DoS is not my concern compared to say Flash exploits or password interception. Don't know what CORS abuse can do inside a web worker..?

Comment: @Besrl: If your website has permission to talk to other domains, then any malicious code ran in the worker could potentially exploit this trust when running as the XSS victim.

Comment: Very good point and this is the case. If the worker sends an XmlHttpRequest and the cookie gets attached, the doors are wide open.

Comment: @Besrl: Although if your app is running from the local file system, the CORS origin will be `null`. IE appears to allow requests and allow them to be read, but only after asking the user if they want to run local scripts or Active-X content.